# Non-intersecting lines on class diagram

Tags: metapost, metauml

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}

\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]
Class.A("A")()();
Class.B("B")()();
Class.C("C")()();
Class.D("D")()();

B.n = A.s + (0,-80);
C.w = D.w + (-80,0);
A.s = C.w + (50,40);
drawObjects(A, B, C, D);
clink(association)(A,B);
clink(association)(C,D);
\end{mpost}
\end{document}
```

The ouput I get:
[image: what I get]

As you can see lines A--B and C--D intersect.

I really need something like this:

[image: what I need]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at section 8 and especially subsection 8.5 of the [`metauml`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/metauml) [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/metauml).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}

\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]
Class.A("A")()();
Class.B("B")()();
Class.C("C")()();
Class.D("D")()();

B.n = A.s + (0,-80);
C.w = D.w + (-80,0);
A.s = C.w + (50,40);
drawObjects(A, B, C, D);
clink(association)(A,B);
%clink(association)(C,D);
path cool;
cool := C.e -- C.c+(38,0) .. C.c+(40,2) .. D.c+(-38,0) -- D.w;
link(association)(cool);
\end{mpost}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output of posted code]