# Avoiding line intersection

Tags: intersections

i wanna do something like that: [Non-intersecting lines on class diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69661/non-intersecting-lines-on-class-diagram)

with that:
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/oxidation-and-reduction/

It will be something like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fLoS.png]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the `intersections` library from [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=10pt,outer sep=0pt] (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\[
\tikzmark{c}2:\tikzmark{a}3 + 5:\tikzmark{d}3+\tikzmark{b}2:3+5:3
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[name path=line1,red,->] ([xshift=2pt]a.north east) -- +(0pt,10pt) -| ([xshift=2pt]b.north east);
\path[name path=line2] ([xshift=2pt]c.north east) -- +(0pt,23pt) -| ([xshift=2pt]d.north east);
\draw[name intersections={of=line1 and line2,by={int}},draw,->,red] 
  ([xshift=2pt]c.north east) -- +(0pt,23pt) -| ([yshift=3pt]int) arc(90:-90:2.5pt) -- ([xshift=2pt]d.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to use the ubiquitous `\tikzmark` to place marks for the paths and then to find the intersection of both paths and then draw an arc at the intersection.

The first run of the above code will result in an error:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named intersection-1 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.19 ...{of=line1 and line2,by={int}},draw,->,red]
```

since the coordinates for the marks are not yet known, so the calculation of the intersection of the paths fails. Quitting the compilation and recompiling, should get the desired result.

In chat, **David Carlisle** proposed the following modification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=10pt,outer sep=0pt] (#1) {};%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\tikzmark{c}2:\tikzmark{a}3 + 5:\tikzmark{d}3+\tikzmark{b}2:3+5:3
\]

\expandafter \ifx\csname pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@pgfid\the \csname
pgf@picture@serial@count\endcsname\endcsname\relax
\typeout{no}%
\else
\typeout{yes}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[name path=line1,red,->] ([xshift=2pt]a.north east) -- +(0pt,10pt) -| ([xshift=2pt]b.north east);
\path[name path=line2] ([xshift=2pt]c.north east) -- +(0pt,23pt) -| ([xshift=2pt]d.north east);
\draw[name intersections={of=line1 and line2,by={int}},draw,->,red] 
  ([xshift=2pt]c.north east) -- +(0pt,23pt) -| ([yshift=3pt]int) arc(90:-90:2.5pt) -- ([xshift=2pt]d.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi

\end{document}
```

which doesn't produce errors. The document has to be run three times.

Now **percusse** has provided this alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=10pt,outer sep=0pt] (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\[
\tikzmark{c}2:\tikzmark{a}3 + 5:\tikzmark{d}3+\tikzmark{b}2:3+5:3
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[name path=line1,red,->] ([xshift=2pt]a.north east) -- +(0pt,10pt) -| ([xshift=2pt]b.north east);
\path[name path=line2] ([xshift=2pt]c.north east) -- +(0pt,23pt) -| ([xshift=2pt]d.north east);
\path[name intersections={of=line1 and line2,total=\totinter}] \pgfextra{\xdef\totinter{\totinter}};
\ifnum\totinter=0\relax%
\else
\path[name intersections={of=line1 and line2,by={int}}];
  \draw[,draw,->,red] ([xshift=2pt]c.north east) -- +(0pt,23pt) -| ([yshift=3pt]int) arc(90:-90:2.5pt) -- ([xshift=2pt]d.north east);
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The result is perfect! But when I've tried to compile that i've got an error on this line: 
\path[name intersections={of=line1 and line2,by={int}}];

Comment: @Henrique sound that you are using an old version of PGF. Please process the following document `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfversion

\end{document}` exactly as it is. This will give you your current PGF version. If it's not 2.10, you'll need to updated your packages.

Comment: It says that is 2.10

The error: 
! Package pgf Error: No shape named intersection-1 is known.

Comment: @Henrique I found the problem. Please see my updated answer. You still need to compile twice to get the right positioning.

Comment: After the update, I continue getting the same error. :(

Comment: @Henrique yes; sorry for that. Quit the first compilation (typing "q" in the output console after the error), and then re-compile twice. This shouls produce the desired result. I'll try to find out how to prevent the error on the first compilation.

Comment: I'm on Windows, so I'm using TeXworks. And I've tried this code on ShareLaTex (online editor) too. It wont compile.

Comment: It worked! Thanks, that is what i need. If you can solute the problem of needing a second compilation it would be perfect. However, thanks.

Comment: @Henrique after quitting the first run and re-compiling, it works: If you use TeXworks, you can activate the console in the upper menu Window->Show Output Console. After the error message, type "q" in the lower window of the output console. Re-run the document and it should work. Anyways I am trying to make the code compilable from the first run.

Comment: @Henrique Ah, our messages crossed. Yes, I will try to solve the problem with the first run.

Comment: There's no problem with a need of a recompile. To finish, can you help me to put a text above the lines? Like in the example of the 'Oxidation'.

Comment: @Henrique sure! You can use a node: replace the last `\draw` lines in my example with `\draw[name intersections={of=line1 and line2,by={int}},draw,->,red] 
  ([xshift=2pt]c.north east) -- +(0pt,23pt) -| node[near start,above] {some text} ([yshift=3pt]int) arc(90:-90:2.5pt) -- ([xshift=2pt]d.north east);`

Comment: @Henrique please see my updated answer. The last code doesn't produce errors on the first run.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hehe! :-)

Comment: Great! Actually run on the first time. ;]